# Adding values to array of structs causes Seg Fault

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, segmentation-fault, elf

So I have a program where I make an array of structs, and then I go through each struct and insert values into each. Only problem is, when I try to insert these values, I hit a segmentation fault. Forgive me, I'm a novice C programmer, but I've looked around and can't find an answer to my problem.

Here's the code (refactored for simplicity):

```
#include "readelf.h"


int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int elf_shnum, sh_name_index, i;
    Section_t *sections;

    i = 0;
    elf_shnum = 12;
    sh_name_index = 24;

    sections = malloc(elf_shnum * sizeof(Section_t));

    sections[i].header->sh_name = sh_name_index;

    return (0);
}
```

include file:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct
{
  uint64_t  sh_name;                /* Section name (string tbl index) */
  uint64_t  sh_type;                /* Section type */
  uint64_t  sh_flags;               /* Section flags */
  uint64_t  sh_addr;                /* Section virtual addr at execution */
  uint64_t  sh_offset;              /* Section file offset */
  uint64_t  sh_size;                /* Section size in bytes */
  uint64_t  sh_link;                /* Link to another section */
  uint64_t  sh_info;                /* Additional section information */
  uint64_t  sh_addralign;           /* Section alignment */
  uint64_t  sh_entsize;             /* Entry size if section holds table */
} Elf_Big_Shdr_t;

typedef union
{
    Elf32_Shdr Elf32;
    Elf64_Shdr Elf64;
} Elf_Shdr_t;

typedef struct
{
    Elf_Big_Shdr_t *header;
    unsigned char *data;
} Section_t;
```

Comment: I think that making a [mcve] would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch, I just added the data structures. I'm hesitant to provide the whole code because it's a lot.

Comment: I'll try to recreate it in a smaller form factor

Comment: Please study the concept of making a [mcve]. It does not mean posting a lot of code. Include only the minimal code needed to demonstrate the problem. That might be quite some work.

Comment: Yes, "smaller form factor" is probably exactly the idea. Good luck with that.... Actually I firmly believe that making a good MCVE is extremely lucky and will almost guarantee either finding the problem yourself or a helpful answer here.

Comment: @Yunnosch Almost every time I want to ask a question here, I start making an MCVE, and then I find the answer and don't actually need to ask anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You malloc Section_t table and it is ok,

`sections = malloc(elf_shnum * sizeof(Section_t));`

but this struct consist next pointer `Header`

```
typedef struct
{
    Elf_Big_Shdr_t *header;
    unsigned char *data;
} Section_t;
```

Before you use it you should alloc memory for it.

for example:

```
sections[i].header = malloc(sizeof(Elf_Big_Shdr_t));
sections[i].header->sh_name = sh_name_index;
```

Alternatively you can change struct definition to

```
typedef struct
{
    Elf_Big_Shdr_t header;
    unsigned char *data;
} Section_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
sections = malloc(elf_shnum * sizeof(Section_t));
```

allocates a bunch of data, and stores it to `sections`. The actual data in the allocated memory is indeterminate. Then, on your next line

```
sections[i].header->sh_name = sh_name_index;
```

you try to treat some of that memory (`sections[0].header`) as a pointer and dereference it. However, since the value is indeterminate, this is undefined behavior. The most probable, and least problematic, result is a segfault.

Instead, you need to assign useful values to each `Section_t` before using it. You can do this by `malloc`ing enough space for the Elf header and assigning the result to `sections[i].header`, but unless Elf sections can have multiple headers or zero headers, it might be a better idea to make the `header` member have type `Elf_Big_Shdr_t` instead of `Elf_Big_Shdr_t *`.